# Why does the map take so long to display and appear distorted?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have map rendered from geoserver but it takes too much time, again shown map is half-shown and distorted as the following image, **SOMETIMES THE MAP DOES NOT EVEN DISPLAY**

[image: my distorted map in open-layer]
 My JAI setting is as below

```
<jai>
    <allowInterpolation>false</allowInterpolation>
    <recycling>false</recycling>
    <tilePriority>5</tilePriority>
    <tileThreads>7</tileThreads>
    <memoryCapacity>0.5</memoryCapacity>
    <memoryThreshold>0.75</memoryThreshold>
    <imageIOCache>1</imageIOCache>
    <pngAcceleration>true</pngAcceleration>
    <jpegAcceleration>true</jpegAcceleration>
    <allowNativeMosaic>false</allowNativeMosaic>
</jai>
```

URL IS

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/it.geosolutions/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=it.geosolutions:thanaboundary&styles=&bbox=88.1099243164063,21.1824684143066,92.5484466552734,26.4899482727051&width=428&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers
```

My PostGIS DataBase Content in SQL is as below

```
  -- Table: thana

  -- DROP TABLE thana;

  CREATE TABLE thana
  (
        gid serial NOT NULL,
        objectid integer,
        recid numeric,
        geocode numeric,
        div_code numeric,
        div_name character varying(254),
        dist_code numeric,
        dist_name character varying(254),
        thana_name character varying(254),
        thana_code numeric,
        shape_leng numeric,
        shape_area numeric,
        noofbed double precision,
        bedoccupen double precision,
        dailyavgop double precision,
        geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
        CONSTRAINT thana_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
  )
 WITH (
       OIDS=FALSE
      );
       ALTER TABLE thana
       OWNER TO postgres;

  -- Index: thana_geom_gist

  -- DROP INDEX thana_geom_gist;

          CREATE INDEX thana_geom_gist
          ON thana
          USING gist
          (geom);
```

My geoserver web page

[image]

Would any one with any tweak please

Comment: What is the data source you are trying to display? That is, what was the original format, and how do you have it set up in your geoserver instance?

Comment: thanks a lot for ur quick reply , my data source is POSTGIS table

Comment: Please explain what you inserted into the table, and how.

Comment: @BradHards   thanks a lot for ur quick reply , my data source is POSTGIS table (loaded shp), and instance is  -------->  workspace (it.geosolutions)>>>data store (bou i.e. boundary)>>>layer(thanaboundary).

Comment: Where did you get the shapefile?

Comment: I have made it in arcmap

Comment: I think there might be some issue with the spatial reference. In addition, how many features do you have in total?

Comment: @devdatta-tengshe, what u mean by how many feature (in data store/workspace/) I have added the snapshot in the question.

Comment: @msi_g I was asking about the number of records or rows in the thana table.

Comment: @devdatta-tengshe 
1). thanaboundary (also layer name in geoserver) shapefile has 825 records (also other boundary has less records )2).thana (also layer name in geoserver) shapefile has 465 records